# Saving bandwidth for Firebase Realtime Database by enabling offline support

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bandwidth

I wondering if enabling offline support in the clients for the Firebase Realtime Database saves you any bandwidth?
I wonder if the Firebase client when starting loads the database from storage and then continue on and only syncs the stuff that has been added later? Or does it sync everything and if that doesn't work fallbacks to the offline data that he has stored before.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I talked to a Googler today at Google Next Amsterdam and he confirmed the  theory that I have. 
If you have offline support enabled in your app and you are going from offline to online state, Firebase will sync your database in the smartest way possible. So that means that if it's possible it will only send over the changed values. So, enabling offline support does save you bandwidth.

Comment: In my opinion it's correct what you just said, `Firebase will sync your database in the smartest way possible.`. But as i mentioned earlier, when you are getting back online, only the changes that are made while you were offline, are updated on `Firebase servers`. But saying let's go offline to save same bandwidth, in my opinion is wrong :|

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't go offline to save bandwidth.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope i've been clear enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` means that you'll be able to query your the database even if you are offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of your database. Every change that is made while you are offline, will be updated on Firebase servers once you are back online. So this option is not used to save bandwidth, is to [enable offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

To be more clear, every client that is using a Firebase database and uses `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database. When data is updated, it is **first written to this local version of the database**.

> As a result, all writes to Firebase will trigger local events immediately, before any data has even been written to the server. This means that the app will remain responsive regardless of Internet connectivity.

Once the Internet connectivity is reestablished, you'll receive the appropriate  current server state. The Firebase client `synchronizes` that data with the Firebase servers and with other clients that are using the same database.

Another thing to remember is that Firebase automatically manages `connection state` to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no `active listeners`, no pending write or `onDisconnect` operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the `goOffline` method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

As a conclusion, there is no difference regarding bandwidth when we are enabling offline support. The benefit is that we can query and change the database even if we are not connected to the internet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not answering the question at all.